# What is Kaku's equation about?

Tags: string-theory, string-field-theory

When Michio Kaku talks about science he often likes to refer to string theory and [sometimes](http://youtu.be/0NbBjNiw4tk?t=1873) to his equation which looks like this (not sure if wrote right):
$$L = \Phi^\dagger[i\partial_{\tau}-H]\Phi + \Phi^{\dagger} \ast \Phi \ast\Phi .$$
It appears to me like some field theory Lagrangian with an interacting and a free part but I have no idea what it actually describes.

Can all of string theory really be summarised in this equation? Can someone give a brief description?

Comment: Related: http://www.quora.com/What-does-Dr-Michio-Kakus-equation-mean

Comment: Isn't that the equation Homer Simpson came up with when he temporarily became a genius in 1998?  Just before he correctly predicted the mass of the Higgs Boson.

Comment: Why don't you ask Dr Kaku?  You can contact him on Facebook.

Comment: I don't recommend taking Michio Kaku seriously, He is clearly out of touch with physics. This equation is just an arbitrary Lagrangian in string field theory confirmed by him (here https://youtu.be/0NbBjNiw4tk?si=9yGpy5BtQow05o5Y). This Lagrangian cannot be experimentally measured with our current technology even a century from now. Also, this equation only describes the basics, it doesn't even incorporate supersymmetry

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic term would give the propagation of the free string, and once  ΦΦ  and  Φ+Φ+  are unpacked we can say what kind of string theory this is. Probably a purely bosonic string if Kaku wrote it in the 1970's.

The second term is a standard interaction vertex which splits one string into two or joins two strings into one - a splitting/joining operator.

**FOR MORE INFORMATION CLICK BELOW LINK:**
http://www.studygtu.com/2016/02/what-is-meaning-of-michio-kakus-equation.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the link containing studygtu.com is now dead.